# Linux (on T430) upower and acpi battery not showing correct info

Tags: linux, battery, thinkpad

I've acquired a used Thinkpad T430. Using it, everything seems stable and it performs like a champ. It didn't come with a battery, so I bought a "DTK" aftermarket battery. I've flashed the BIOS using the well known patch on github, to get around Lenovo's attempt to only let you use genuine OEM batteries. The battery charges and I can use it.

Sometimes the battery's state is reported correctly. I'm using gnome-power-statistics show me a graph how it is performing over time. Using upower and acpi from the command line to reveal its state.

But then suddenly, out of the blue, at varying charge levels, it suddenly shows 0%, empty. Once it does that, rebooting, removing / reinserting the battery, doesn't fix it. I can not get the charge level information from the battery at that point. The battery is not actually empty. I can use it for the expected number of hours. The battery charges and discharges at expected rates. Except the information about the charge disappears suddenly. I've looked to see if there is a poor connection between the laptop's pins and the battery. It looks fine. I'm wondering if there is a loose contact with a ribbon cable onto the motherboard perhaps - I haven't checked that yet.
I'm wondering if the battery itself is bad. Does the battery have an embedded computer that reports to the laptop its state? Are aftermarket batteries expected to be flaky when it comes to reporting its charge? Or perhaps the entire process of charging, discharging, discharge time, and measuring voltage and whatnot, is entirely done on the laptop's end, while the battery is just a bunch of cells in a case with no logic in it at all?

Does anyone have any ideas how to further troubleshoot it, and to find a fix / solution / workaround, before I complain to the battery's seller asking for a replacement or refund?

Comment: Might be a side effect of the hacked bios?

Comment: @Moab If that were the case I think I would have come across someone bringing this up across my T430 Google ventures. I just replaced the keyboard with a modded T420 one, upgraded the ram, flashed the bios to include both the battery patch and the keyboard patch. So far, the battery status is working. I bet it'll soon lose the status though. I'm peeking around proc and sys and see what I can record for reference if and when it fails again.
As for what I find people talk about, it's usually about it not working at all until it's fixed, but never about it being flaky or intermittent.

Comment: It's doing it again. 0% "battery is empty". It's not. It's just not communicating with the battery.

Comment: It went from 43% to 0% suddenly. The OS (Xubuntu 18.04) complained but I kept going. 10 minutes later, screen goes black. To my surprise it would boot without recharging. Indicates 0% again. Go for another 10 to 15 minutes. Poof black again. Reboot yet again without charging. Indicator now indicating 36% charge.
It's starting to smell more and more like a defective battery. But how could a battery be flaky in this way I wonder.

Comment: FWIW, I've bought a second battery, and this one isn't showing these problems at all. The first battery is deemed defective, and it's going back to the seller.
Weird how a battery can act up like that. Perhaps someone in the future will see erratic behavior also, where this question might offer a quicker solution.
I've read elsewhere that a hardware IT guy managing Lenovo laptops where this is typical with end of life batteries. Just that this one was a new one (aftermarket one).

Comment: Mike, you can write an answer to your own question and then accept it as the answer in a few days.